# Simple Pandas df calculation lost in infinity

Tags: python, pandas

## Setup

I have medium sized df (600K by 40) and I am trying to add element wise (by index) series values together and then create a new column with the subsequent values.  However, it is taking over 24 hours and has not yet finished.

#### First I make two series:

#### (from the original df with some constraints)

```
 Series1 = df.loc[df['ColumnX'] == 5, 'ColumnY']
 Series2 = df.loc[df['ColumnX'] == 6, 'ColumnY']
```

#### Second I add them to together and insert as a new column into original df:

```
 df['column1plus2'] = Series1 + Series2
```

It simply shouldn't take longer than 24 hours on a weak-medium powered server to compute, should it? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the mutually exclusive nature of your selection (5 vs 6), the indexes of *all* rows in `Series1` are different from the indexes of *all* rows in `Series2`. The operator `+` uses *data alignment* to find the matching rows, and it cannot. So, instead it creates matching dummies with the values of `NaN` and adds them to the values from your series. (The result is also a `NaN`, of course.) For example, if you had row #10 in `Series1` (with the value of, say, 3.14), there will be no row with the same number in `Series2`. Pandas will create row #10 in `Series2` and set its value to `NaN`, because it doesn't know any better. The result of the summation in row #10 is now `3.14+NaN=NaN`.

This explains why your code is **wrong** but not necessarily why it is slow. I would guess that data alignment is a very slow operation in the presence of so many missing values.

Did you mean to stack `Series1` and `Series2` instead of arithmetically adding them? If so, you should do `pd.concat[Stack1,Stack2])`.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it would re-index the Series. I guess I have to add them by a different index (one that they do indeed share). Hopefully, this also speeds it up.

Comment: Thanks for the response. They do in fact share indices so it seems they should be able to **add** elements of each series together and then make a new column in the df under the new column name and index. Most scripts with this dataset take only a minute or two.

Comment: Sharing the index is exactly the problem, because no two rows have the same index key. Two series extracted from the same column in a mutually exclusive way, will always have this problem.